# Delete all Tag Links from Posts

Tags: posts, tags, links

We're working on this site:
http://granthammond.staging.wpengine.com/
which will no longer be using tags, 
i need a way to strip / remove all the tag links in the post content, 
for example:
any hyperlinks containing `/tag/` need to go, in their entirety,

```
<a href="http://www.granthammond.com/tag/nashville-real-estate/">Tagged with: Nashville Real Estate</a>
```

i need to remove the whole `<a>` element. for all tags, across all posts.

as usual, any and all assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Do the links need to be removed in the database, or is it OK just to filter the output to remove the links before the post is shown to the user?

Comment: At this point, either is good. Ideally, removing them from the database would preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For existing post content, you can add a filter to `the_content` to remove them from the output before they are seen by a user:

```
function remove_tag_links( $content ) {
    return preg_replace( '#<a [^>]*\bhref=\\\?"[^"]+(?=/tag/)[^"]+\\\?"[^>]*>(.+?)</a>#si', '$1', $content );
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_tag_links' );
```

2) For new / updating content, you can add the same filter to `content_save_pre` to take the links out before they are saved to the database:

```
add_filter( 'content_save_pre', 'remove_tag_links' );
```

Note that my pattern expects double-quotes (and possibly backslashed-escaped double quotes, for `content_save_pre`) around the href attribute value, and can handle other attributes within the tag.

The filter I provided simply removes the link markup, but leaves behind the text. If you want to remove the entire tag including its text, pass an empty string `''` instead of `'$1'` as the second parameter to `preg_replace`

Comment: I just noticed that my pattern was greedy. I have updated it to by non-greedy by adding a `?` after the `+` quantifier in the capture group. Be sure to incorporate this change: otherwise bad things will happen if a targeted link appears in the middle of the text, followed by another one further in the content.

Answer (score 0):

To your themes functions.php file, add the following:

```
add_filter( 'the_tags', 'remove_links' );
function remove_links($thelist) {
  return preg_replace('#<a.*?>([^<]*)</a>#i', '$1', $thelist);
}
```